# Multi option range filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'm trying to filter an array of objects based on their abw value which is a range. Now I can filter based on one range selection but can't seem to figure out for multiple range selections. I tried many ways but they seems to override each other. Any help appreciated.

Also the range options are dynamic so I can't use static if else statements.

```
var selectedABW = [ [0, 5], [5, 10], [10,20], [20, 30] ] //dynamic data
var p2 = [{name: "dank", abw: 29}, {name: "jank", abw: 5}, {name: "bank", abw: 1000}]

 p2.filter(({ abw }) => {
       for (var item of this.selectedABW) {
          const range = this.getValuesFromABW(item);
            if (!(abw >= range[0] && abw <= range[1])) {
              return false;
            }
       }
       return true;
    });
```

> Expected output: [{name: "dank", abw: 29}, {name: "jank", abw: 5}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `.some` test to see if any of the items in `selectedABW` fulfill the condition for the `abw` property of the object:

```js
var selectedABW = [ [0, 5], [5, 10], [10,20], [20, 30] ]
var p2 = [{name: "dank", abw: 29}, {name: "jank", abw: 5}, {name: "bank", abw: 1000}]

const result = p2.filter(
  ({ abw }) => selectedABW.some(
    ([low, high]) => abw >= low && abw <= high
  )
);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfect..I didn't know such a method exists in arrays.